# Python script does not run after string replace by powershell

Tags: python, powershell, character-encoding

I created a Python script on one of my computers. A powershell script replaces some drive and folder names, and copies it to the computer where it is supposed to run.
Unfortunately it does not run there. The only unintended difference I observed is that the copy on the remote computer is twice as big as on the development computer, so I suspect some encoding problem.

How can I solve this?

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\Users\<me>\eclipse-workspace\felirat\felirat.py) 
-replace 'c:/install/felirat', 'd:' | Out-File l:\install\felirat\felirat.py"
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code. Have you run a `diff` of the source and destination files? Tried it without the path modification? Or with a simpler test script?

Comment: It's a really bad idea to change scripts with other scripts, why not have the script accept arguments (for paths for example)?

Answer (score 1):

The default file encoding for PowerShell is 16 bit Unicode which explains why the modified script is twice as large. To save it as utf-8, write the modified script to disk using `$script | Out-File -Encoding utf8 outputfile.py`